# I have this fizzbuzz problem and I really don't know how to solve it Can somebody help me?

Tags: ruby

Convert ["a", nil, "b", "c", nil] and ["d", nil, "e", "f"] into ["af", "be", "cd"] using Ruby in one sentence
Hint: Remember, Do it in one sentence.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the principle of forming a new array?

Comment: Hello, so far I have only been able to perform the numerical fizzbuzz sequence, but I have not been able to do the same with this array and organize it

Comment: Could you help me with an example to know what steps I must follow, I am very new to programming with ruby and this exercise is costing me

Comment: There are probably a dozen different ways to do what you're attempting, but I'll give you a few things to start with.  Look into the ```#Array.compact```, ```#Array.reverse```, ```#Array.zip```, ```reverse_each```, ```#Array.map```, and ```Array.join``` methods to get some ideas.

Comment: How is this a fizzbuzz problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with:

```
a = ["a", nil, "b", "c", nil]
b = ["d", nil, "e", "f"]

a.compact.zip(b.compact.reverse).map(&:join)
#=> ["af", "be", "cd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a", nil, "b", "c", nil]
b = ["d", nil, "e", "f"]

a.compact.map{ |x| [x,b.compact.pop].join }
#=> ["af", "be", "cd"]
```